# Class Function Syntax Confusion

Tags: c++, class, syntax

I have the following function:

```
int Player::calcInitiative(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int& diceRoll) {

int Init = 0;

Init = (Lvl/2) + Dex + Mod + diceRoll;

return Init;
}
```

Elsewhere I have instantiated several objects like so:

```
Player Derek("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);
```

I now want to use the function, and so have attempted:

```
Derek.calcInitiative;
```

But the compiler tells me the argument list is missing. I don't want to retype the arguments in the call, since they are already defined for the player, as above. I thought my above call would be enough. How can I change it so that it will recognize the traits the player already has?

Comment: If you want to use the member variables, use the member variables, don't bother with parameters to the function.  Or implement an overload to the function with no parameters that calls the parameterized function with the member variables as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify the correct number and type of parameters to your function:

Based on the function definition:

```
 calcInitiative(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int& diceRoll)
```

It requires you pass `string, int, int, int, int` type parameters.

```
 Derek.calcInitiative;
```

should be:

```
//calling outside class scope
Derek.calcInitiative(getName(), getDex(), getMod(), getLvl(), getDiceRoll());
//^^assume that get*() are getters and your class members are private
```

The point is that you `MUST` provide correct number and type of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that you supplied in

```
Player Derek("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);
```

are arguments that passed to the *constructor* of class `Player`. They have absolutely no relation to the arguments of function `calcInitiative`. Your `calcInitiative`, as written, has its own, independent set of arguments. And you will have to specify these arguments every time you call `calcInitiative`. There's no way around it.

If you are the one who wrote class `Player`, then you should understand it already. If you wanted to write `calcInitiative` so that it would be callable without any arguments, then you should have done exactly that. But you declared it as

```
calcInitiative(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int& diceRoll)
```

and that means it requires arguments.